# .htaccess file not working

Tags: .htaccess

I'm on CentOS 5 with Apache. I'm trying to make this directory get a 403 error and it still continues to show the index of.

Here's the .htaccess file. I gave it 644 permissions:

```
Options –Indexes
```

Thanks!

Comment: May I ask why my question was downvoted? I'm happy to supply more information at request. I don't really know what information I'd supply though. Let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have root access on the box?  or can you request that changes be made to the apache configuration?

Comment: full root access

Comment: if you can edit the apache configuration, then you should NOT be using .htaccess files.  just put the configuration you need into the server config.  Changing stuff in .htaccess is disabled by default because it opens up security problems and can have a big performance hit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are the main config for that site doesn't have -/+Indexes allowed in it's `AllowOverride` [directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride)

Comment: Thanks for the responce. Should it be set to this:
AllowOverride None

Comment: This is what it currently is:
<Directory "/var/www/error">
 AllowOverride None
 Options IncludesNoExec
 AddOutputFilter Includes html
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
 LanguagePriority en es de fr
 ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
</Directory>

Comment: That's your problem :) `AllowOverride Indexes`

Comment: Do I change the AllowOverride in <Directory "/var/www/error">  or <Directory /> ?

Answer (score 0):

The directory listing could be cached in your browser.  Try clearing your browser cache, or pressing Shift+Reload.

Comment: I just tried that, no luck. Thanks for the suggestion though, didn't think of that.